How to stop the sound player when I move to next screen
I want to stop the sound player whenever I move to next screen in app.
const [shallPlay, setPlay] = useState(true);

useEffect(() =\> {
if (shallPlay) {
try {
SoundPlayer.playSoundFile("om_namo`your text`\_venkateshaya", ".mp3");
} catch (e) {
console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e);
}
} else {
SoundPlayer.stop();
}
}, \[shallPlay\]);

\<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => {
setPlay(!shallPlay);
}}
>

I am new to react native. Unable to find the solution

You can use useFocusEffect

import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const [shallPlay, setPlay] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (shallPlay) {
    try {
      SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('om_namo_venkateshaya', '.mp3');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('cannot play the sound file', e);
    }
} else {
  SoundPlayer.stop();
}   }, [shallPlay]);

useFocusEffect(
   React.useCallback(() => {
     // This will run when the screen is focused

  return () => {
    // This will run when the screen is unfocused
    // Stop the sound player when navigating away
    SoundPlayer.stop();
  };
}, [])   );

